# Python import from a module with "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: python, flask, import

I have a directory that looks like this:

```
├── libraryweb
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── forms.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── routes.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   ├── save_books.py
│   ├── site.db
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── book_pics
│   │   └── user_pics
│   │       └── default.jpg
│   └── templates
│       ├── account.html
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── book.html
│       ├── book_update.html
│       ├── home.html
│       ├── login.html
│       └── register.html
└── run.py
```

Now in the file `save_books.py`, I want to import a class `Book` from `models.py` in the `libraryweb` module. I have tried `from libraryweb.models import Book`, `from .models import Book`, and `from models import Book`, but none of them works.

The `__init__.py` file contains the following code:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view='login'
login_manager.login_message_category='info'

from libraryweb import routes
```

I got the following error message:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'libraryweb'
  File "/Users/gracezhou/cs/python_flask/flask-library/hey/libraryweb/save_books.py", line 3, in <module>
    from libraryweb.models import Book
```

Comment: What was the problem when you used `from .models import Book`?

Comment: Could you pot your code from ```__init__.py```

Comment: Actually, this looks pretty good. `from .models import Book` should work. I have the same directory tree, except I wrapped it into a `src` top level dir. I would set a breakpoint in your `save_books.py` and try to find out what is going on. Debugging is not too hard .. see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fxkco-gS4S8

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace / error message.

Comment: @mkrieger1 It reports `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: @J.G. The problem occurs at the first line of the code, so I received `Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'libraryweb'` while debugging. I guess it occurred because the `sys.path` did not include the current working directory, but I can't figure out why. I have to manually add that before importing anything from `libraryweb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set your PYTHONPATH variable pointing to your application path ?

Can you please show your ouput of below command.

import sys

sys.path

All directories where module files are exist needed to be in PYTHONPATH env variable. If you dump everything in the single directory then you just need folder which contains python files into your PYTHONPATH. Refer to below https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path

Comment: You are right. The sys.path does not contain the path of the directory. But can you tell me why is that? I thought that the current working directory will be automatically added to the path. Thank you.

Comment: This one is common module error. This is because you might be trying to run your app from run.py and its on different level directory than your other module files. run.py file directory must be present in your path when you invoke the program. Anyway you got the problem add that path and it will fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. My program is running perfectly again.